# A question on singular value .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

***Weyl's inequality***

If $A,B\in M_{n*n}$ are hermitian, and ${\lambda _1}(A) \ge {\lambda _2}(A) \ge {\rm{ \cdot \cdot \cdot}} \ge {\lambda _n}(A)$ are eigenvalues of $A$ then ${\lambda _n}(A + B) \le {\lambda _n}(A) + {\lambda _1}(B)$

***Now let***

$A,B\in M_{n*n}$ are arbitrary.

Can we prove (by *Weyl's inequality*) that $s_n(A+B) \leq s_n(A) + s_1(B)$, where $s_1(A) ≥ s_2(A) ≥ · · · ≥ s_n(A) ≥ 0$ are singular value of $A$ ?

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel Please more guide.

Comment: Actually, it is better if you apply the Weyl's theorem to the matrix $\pmatrix{0&C^*\\C&0}$, which is *Hermitian* and has the eigenvalues $\{-s_n(C),\ldots,-s_1(C),s_1(C),\ldots,s_n(C)\}$.

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel And next....?Is Is this true that $C=A+B$?Please complete this proof.